# convert audio to libopus with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm totally new to ffmpeg and use it on windows.
I want to encode the audio from a mkv video to opus, using

```
ffmpeg -i abc.mkv -map 0:v -c copy -map 0:a -c libopus -b:a 128000 xyz.mkv
```

but I get the error:

```
invalid encoder type "libopus".
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `-c` on its own will set the encoder for all types of streams: video, audio..etc. libopus can't encode video, obviously. You need to attach a stream specifier to limit it to audio, so

```
ffmpeg -i abc.mkv -map 0:v -c copy -map 0:a -c:a libopus -b:a 128k xyz.mkv
```

See the section on [stream specifiers](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-specifiers-1) and also this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1219824/114058) on how multiple codec settings in a command works.